# Prove or disprove regarding continuity of $f$ and $g$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove or disprove:

> Let, $f,g:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous in $[a,b]$ and are non-zero at any point.
>
> There exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $$g(c)\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=f(c)\int_a^b g(x)\,dx.$$

I tried to define a function $F$ , such that I can apply Bolzano's theorem of continuity to $F$  ..But I could not find it..

Please help to define such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function: $h(x)=F(x)\int_a^bg(t)dt-G(x)\int_a^bf(t)dt$ Which: $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ and $G(x)=\int_a^xg(t)dt$. Then: $h(a)=h(b)=0$.

Comment: I think you want to apply Roll's theorem...Right ??

Comment: yes. your right.